# Modal Window creates grey overlay over entire page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=show-bootstrap-modal-on-page-load) to have a Modal window displayed on Page Load.

However, when the page loads the modal display but there is a grey overlay over the entire page that I can't close ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbGjV.png).)

I am using Bootstrap 4.5.3 & JQuery 3.6.3 . For reference here is the CSS for the modal:

```
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
```

I am expecting the modal window to be displayed without the overlay and to be able to close it.

[SOLVED]: Changed the z-index to 2000 which resolved the issue.

Comment: provide code sandbox or demo of the whole setup, html, css, js

Comment: Hi Zeeshawn, there must be some JS involved that triggers the modal, so we need that part included in your question, please.

Comment: @ZeeshawnAli please edit the question. Don't post code in the comments

Comment: Please read - How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)